# How to set theta limit in -90 to 90 range in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axes

How to set theta range from 0 to 90 and 270 to 360 in a single plot.

```
thetalim([theta_lower,theta_upper])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To set it from -90° to 90°, just set it from -90° to 90° i.e.

```
%Creating a random polar plot with same ThetaDir and ThetaZeroLocation as yours
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi);
rho = rand(1, 100);
polarplot(theta, rho);
ax = gca;
set(ax,'ThetaDir', 'clockwise', 'ThetaZeroLocation', 'top');

%Setting the desired limits
thetalim([-90 90]);
```

[image]

and if you want to have positive values for `theta` then you can change the ticklabels as follows:

```
ax.ThetaTickLabel = wrapTo360(ax.ThetaTick); %requires Mapping Toolbox
% or without Mapping Toolbox:
% ax.ThetaTickLabel(ax.ThetaTick<0) = split(num2str(ax.ThetaTick(ax.ThetaTick<0) + 360));
```

[image]